# Не запускается следующее activity?

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте. У меня не запускается следующее активити. Проблема не в ID элементов. 3аранее спасибо.

Вот ошибка:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: kz.yensanova.logika_alemi, PID: 1510
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2115)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                      at android.view.View.(View.java:3554)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
                      at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:87)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:60)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
                      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at kz.yensanova.logika_alemi.ActivityKaz2.onCreate(ActivityKaz2.java:17)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1510 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

xml-код:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/samal"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton152"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton151"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton151" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/lupa"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton153"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />


<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/ertegiler"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton156"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton155" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fotoapparat"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton153"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton153" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sayakhat"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton157"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton152"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton154" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/talap"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton153"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton152"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton152" />
```

Java-код второго активити:
public class ActivityKaz2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton imageButton151, imageButton152, imageButton153, imageButton154, imageButton155, imageButton156, imageButton157;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    **setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaz2);** //говорит, что ошибка здесь

    imageButton151 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton151);
    imageButton152 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton152);
    imageButton153 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton153);
    imageButton154 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton154);
    imageButton155 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton155);
    imageButton156 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton156);
    imageButton157 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton157);
    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eki);
    mediaPlayer1.start();

    imageButton151.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Arman.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton152.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Samal.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton153.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Talap.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton154.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Aizere.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton155.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Ayan.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton156.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Kiziltelpek.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton157.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Sarsen.class);
            startActivity(intent7);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Присмотритесь внимательнее к логам.

У вас по логам **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** (нехватка памяти), при **BitmapFactory.decodeStream** (декодировании изображения для отображения). Это происходит, когда вы вызываете тяжелый метод **setContentView**, который начинает отрисовку вашего интерфейса в соответствии с экраном, поэтому оно там и завершается с ошибкой, потому что процесс отрисовки не может завершить свою работу из-за нехватки памяти.

Размер кучи в приложении ограничен и сильно зависит от устройства. Ранние устройства имели вообще 16 мб, потом появилось 32 мб и т.д. Устройствам с высоким разрешением нужно больше памяти для хранения изображения и т.д.

1. Посмотрите, может у вас используется очень большое изображение или изображения? Уменьшите их в пиксельном размере, возможно такая огромная картинка вам и не нужна на мобильных телефонах и планшетах? Вы загружаете большое изображение, система его масштабирует "на лету", что приводит к дополнительным задержкам.
2. Если нужны огромные картинки, то возможно не стоит их загружать сразу все, а грузить с помощью кода на Java по мере необходимости и оценивать текущее состояние ресурсов. [На официальном сайте есть информация по работе с bitmap](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)
3. Увеличить heap size, но это так себе вариант, при большом количестве маленьких обьектов в куче это вам даст дополнительные тормоза на всем пользовательском интерфейсе. Этот метод хорош, когда вы точно знаете, почему именно этот набор данных должен храниться в памяти. Ну предположим, вы разработчик фоторедактора, где огромная фотка ну никак не помещается. Я не советую использовать это для отрисовки интерфейса, даже если обьектов много, можно оставлять в памяти только видимые, а для остальных освобождать память. [Информация на официальном сайте](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Убрала лишние изображения и все работает!